# Play with subprojects routes

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.5, playframework-routing

I have a Play! 2.5.3 project with one subproject (with its own routes). In the main routes file the subproject's routes are defined as follows:

```
->        /api                         api.Routes
GET       /assets/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and the `api.routes` file is as folllows:

```
GET      /v1/permissions/roles         controllers.api.PermissionsController.roles
```

So the URL fro getting the roles would be `/api/v1/permissions/roles`.

When I run the root project (which depends on both subprojects) everything works fine, but when running each subproject separately, the routes are not found. I tried copying the main routes file to the `conf` folder of the built subproject during the build, but it didn't work.

The only solution I found was adding `play.http.router = "api.Routes"` in `application.conf`, but the routes "looses" its `/api` prefix (ie: the api route is `/v1/permissions/roles`)

So my question is: **is it possible to have a subproject with routes, and these routes be the same when running the root project and when running each subproject separately?**

And if it's possible, is it anywhere in the docs?

**EDIT:**

`build.sbt` for the root project

```
name := """abc"""
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
javaOptions in Test += "-Dtest.timeout=600000"


lazy val abcCore = (project in file("modules/abc-core")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

lazy val abcCentral = (project in file("modules/abc-central")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .dependsOn(abcCore)
    .aggregate(abcCore)

lazy val abcSimulador = (project in file("modules/abc-simulador")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .dependsOn(abcCore)
    .aggregate(abcCore)


lazy val abcDevice = (project in file("modules/abc-device")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .dependsOn(abcCore)
    .aggregate(abcCore)

lazy val abcApi = (project in file("modules/abc-api")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .dependsOn(abcCore, abcSimulador)
    .aggregate(abcCore, abcSimulador)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .dependsOn(abcCore, abcDevice, abcCentral, abcSimulador, abcApi)
    .aggregate(abcCore, abcDevice, abcCentral, abcSimulador, abcApi)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    "uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "2.0.0-jongo1.3",
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.5.0",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-validator" % "5.2.4.Final",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-joda" % "2.7.5",
    "uk.co.modular-it" % "bean-utils" % "0.9.10",
    "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-library" % "1.3",
    "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.2",
    "net.coobird" % "thumbnailator" % "0.4.8",
    "io.moquette" % "moquette-broker" % "0.8.1" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
    "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6.1",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0",
    "org.thymeleaf" % "thymeleaf" % "3.0.1.RELEASE",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin" % "kotlin-stdlib" % "1.0.3",
    "org.eclipse.collections" % "eclipse-collections-api" % "7.1.0",
    "org.eclipse.collections" % "eclipse-collections" % "7.1.0",
    "org.eclipse.collections" % "eclipse-collections-forkjoin" % "7.1.0",
    "net.jpountz.lz4" % "lz4" % "1.3.0",
    "org.mapdb" % "elsa" % "3.0.0-M6",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0",
    "org.jfree" % "jfreesvg" % "3.1",
    "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports" % "6.3.1",
    "com.github.jhonnymertz" % "java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper" % "1.0.1-RELEASE",
    "org.awaitility" % "awaitility-scala" % "2.0.0",
    "org.fusesource.mqtt-client" % "mqtt-client" % "1.14")


jacoco.settings
parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
jacoco.reportFormats in jacoco.Config := Seq(
    de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.ScalaHTMLReport(encoding = "utf-8", withBranchCoverage = true),
    de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.XMLReport(encoding = "utf-8"))


fork in run := false
fork in Test := false



mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile) map { jar =>
    val scriptsDir = new java.io.File("modules/abc-api/app/templates/")
    scriptsDir.listFiles.toSeq.map { f =>
        f -> ("app/templates/" + f.getName)
    }
}

mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile) map { jar =>
    val scriptsDir = new java.io.File("modules/abc-api/public/images/")
    scriptsDir.listFiles.toSeq.map { f =>
        f -> ("public/images/" + f.getName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run them separately? could you also share your build.sbt?

Comment: In production each subproject (there are 5 of them) run on its own server, and they communicate through a REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could do that, the projects are binary bound, I mean all the module jars has to be there in the class path (as per the `build.sbt`). You can not run them individually.

I hope what you are looking is a microservices kind of stuff. If so, you need to be aware of the costs that come with microservices. Once you decide to go with microservices, you can take a look at Lagom Framework (https://www.lightbend.com/lagom)